# iterate through objects and array javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to iterate an object that I get in Angular but I was unable to. In order to understand that I tried it simply using below code:

```
<script>
var x = {"data":['A','B','C']};
for(v in x) 
{
    alert(v[0]);
}   
</script>
```

The output of this is "d".How can I output "A"?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this for loop, this is the syntax:

```
var x = {"data":['A','B','C']};
for(var key in x) 
{
    alert(key);    //data
    alert(x[key]); //A,B,C
}
```

This is plain JS though, no Angular.

You can add further `if` clauses to receive the first element like `A`, but make sure it doesn't error out on other properties of the object.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cw5z4md/)